# Write Lack of Fit Sum of Squares in Quadratic Form

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, quadratic-forms

Let

\begin{equation}
SSLF = \sum_{i=1}^{m}n_{i}(\bar{y_{i}} - \hat{y_{i}})^{2}
\end{equation}

then

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{m}n_{i}(\bar{y_{i}} - \hat{y_{i}})^{2} = n(\bar{\overrightarrow{y}} - \hat{\overrightarrow{y}})'(\bar{\overrightarrow{y}} - \hat{\overrightarrow{y}})
\end{equation}

where $n = (n_{1},...,n_{m})$

and

\begin{equation}
n(\bar{\overrightarrow{y}} - \hat{\overrightarrow{y}})'(\bar{\overrightarrow{y}} - \hat{\overrightarrow{y}}) = n(\bar{\overrightarrow{y}} - H\overrightarrow{y})'(\bar{\overrightarrow{y}} - H\overrightarrow{y})
\end{equation}

where $H$ is the Hat matrix.

I believe I need to work it down to

\begin{equation}
\bar{\overrightarrow{y}}'(I - H)\bar{\overrightarrow{y}}
\end{equation}

So that I can get the degrees of freedom as $m - (k+1)$ but I am having trouble doing that.

Answer (score 1):

the second line is wrong:
$$
\sum n_i (y_i-\hat y_i)^2 = (y-\hat y)^T N (y-\hat y),
$$
where $N$ is diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $n_i$. Using $\hat y = Hy$,
$$
(y-\hat y)^T N (y-\hat y) = ((I-H)y)^T N ((I-H)y) = y^T(I-H)^TN(I-H)y.
$$

Comment: You can't factor the y out like that, ybar and y are different vectors